# Does the beeping satellite shown at the end of NASA Goddard videos represent any spacecraft in particular?

Tags: nasa, history, identify-this-object, space-art, outreach

Just as an example, the end of the NASA Goddard video [NASA’s OSIRIS-REx: Mission to Bennu](https://youtu.be/NYGHbl_esgw) has a double-beeping satellite at the end, which performs a flyby of the camera.

It's shiny and spherical and has four apparently *coplanar* radial antennas <s>that appear to radiate in a tetrahedral pattern</s> and one opposite pair appears to be much longer than the other.

At the end of each antenna theres a shiny metal ball.

**Question:** Does the beeping satellite shown at the end of NASA Goddard videos represent any spacecraft in particular?

Or is it a general "homage" to all of the earliest, pioneering spherical four-antennated satellites that went into orbit in the early years of spaceflight?

---

[image: cropped screenshot from the ending "beeping satellite" scene from a NASA Goddard video]

[image: cropped screenshot from the ending "beeping satellite" scene from a NASA Goddard video]

Comment: Not tetrahedral, the video at 7:36 clearly shows the view from almost inline with the shorter antennas, showing both shorter with same perspective shortening, an the two longer antennas exactly inline with each other. There is another surface or near-surface feature that may be confusing you, it is the one shown top-right of the main body in your image above, but it never shows away from the body from any angle during passage. Very end of video also shows all antenna are co-planar.

Comment: @PcMan while "clearly" is in the eye of the beholder after using the "." and "," keys to move back and forth frame by frame a few times I guess I'm convinced, so I've updated accordingly.